# Unity: Playing Audio via script, and adding audio lisener at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am playing around with Unity and experimenting a bit; I have this code that I am attempting to have to instantiate a cube with a sine.wav file. I want to avoid using the inspector if possible and have things instantiate in run time; here is the code I have; when I run it, everything seems to work as expected, except I don't hear any audio.

```
public class Main : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Spawn cube and add audio listener
        CubeSpawner spawner = gameObject.AddComponent<CubeSpawner>();
        spawner.SpawnCube(new Vector3(10, 10, 10), new Vector3(2, 2, 3));

        // Create a new game object and add an audio listener component to it
        GameObject audioListenerObj = new GameObject("Audio Listener");
        audioListenerObj.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
        audioListenerObj.AddComponent<AudioListener>();
    }
}

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;  // the prefab for the cube we want to spawn

    public void SpawnCube(Vector3 position, Vector3 size)
    {
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube); // create a cube object
        cube.transform.position = position; // set the position of the cube to the specified position
        cube.transform.localScale = size; // set the scale of the cube to the specified size
        cube.AddComponent<Cube>(); // add the Cube script to the cube object
        
        // add Rigidbody component to the cube
        Rigidbody rb = cube.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.mass = 1;
        rb.useGravity = true;

        // add MeshCollider component to the cube
        MeshCollider meshCollider = cube.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
        meshCollider.convex = true;
    }
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float amplitude = 0.5f; // amplitude of the sine wave
    public float frequency = 440f; // frequency of the sine wave
    public float speed = 1f; // speed of the sine wave

    private Vector3 startPosition; // starting position of the cube
    private AudioSource audioSource; // audio source component attached to the cube

    void Start()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position; // store the starting position of the cube
        audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>(); // get the audio source component attached to the cube
        audioSource.loop = true; // enable looping for the audio source
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // calculate the sine wave value based on time
        float time = Time.time * speed;
        float sineValue = amplitude * Mathf.Sin(2 * Mathf.PI * frequency * time);

        // apply the sine wave to the Y position of the cube
        transform.position = startPosition + new Vector3(0f, sineValue, 0f);

        // set the audio source pitch to the sine wave value
        float pitch = Mathf.InverseLerp(-1f, 1f, sineValue);
        audioSource.pitch = Mathf.Lerp(0.5f, 2f, pitch);

        // play the audio source
        if (!audioSource.isPlaying) {
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not how an audio sorce works, you need to give it a sound file, you have not done that, you have just set the pitch modifier.

Comment: @jay, thanks for the help! I added that via the inspector :/  I was trying to eliminate that as an issue.

Comment: You also don't need to add a listener, as there is one on the Main Camera already as should be (since all sound should be relative to your position - including non-locational sounds, such as interface sounds). Also, an AudioSource needs an AudioMixerGroup. Please read up on how Audio works in the Unity manual, don't just try random stuff.